# CDROM does not work in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers

Every time I try to use cdrom it does not start. There is no image on screen of the cdrom device. I conected an external cdrom device and it did not work also. How can I solve this and get my computer working with cd?

Comment: Is it a CD-ROM (data CD), an Audio CD or... ?

Comment: Look [here first](http://askubuntu.com/questions/817293/hash-for-16-04-1) and then have a look if the DVD needs to be reburnt/redownloaded

Comment: There's a parameter that can be set/unset to show mounted disks on the desktop. Yours may be unset. First question... do you see the CD in the Nautilus file manager? Is this a CD drive or a DVD drive? What disc are you inserting into the drive?